# Get all group by values in column a where all values in another column is true

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I wanted to create a query that gives me a group by OrderID and Canbefulfilled but if there is a single 0 in Canbefulfilled column , I want that column to be 0

I the above case I am expecting, since OrderID `30` has one `0`

```
OrderID  CanbeFulfilled
27             0
28             0
30             0
```

Query wise

```
Select OrderID, Return0IfThereIfAny0(CanBeFulFilled)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY OrderID
```

I cannot figure out how I can do the `Return0IfThereIsAny0` part.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Things like providing DDL and usable data, not pictures, help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `min()` does what you want:

```
SELECT OrderID, MIN(CanBeFulFilled)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY OrderID
```